# Spring Session, Websocket, REST Token Security

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security, sockjs, spring-session

We currently have a Spring application which contains a REST API and also Websocket broker endpoints to get realtime updates on database changes.

We've successfully migrated to the Spring Session project with an embedded redis server which authenticates by basic auth and a session id can be used  on subsequent requests as an x-auth-token header.

The issue we're having is to secure the Websocket. On Angular, we have a wrapper directive around the stomp.js / sockjs libraries but we can't seem to figure out how to set the x-auth-token header on the Websocket upgrade requests.

Are we doing something wrong? What would be the recommended way to approach this kind of security scheme?

Stack:

- Tomcat 7.0.57
- Spring Security 4.0.0.RC2
- Spring Session 1.0.0.RELEASE
- Spring MVC 4.1.4
- AngularJS 1.2.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the JS Websocket API doesn't allow setting HTTP headers on the initial handshake and upgrade request.

The proper scheme would be to send an authentication token on the CONNECT frame and handle it accordingly on the server side. So for now we've migrated to browser cookie sessions until we can find a suitable implementation for this on the server side.